Computing the degree of the image of an embedding given by the associated map of a complete linear system
Suppose $S$ is a surface, $D$ a divisor on $S$, and $i:S\to \mathbb{P}^n$ the associated map of the complete linear system $|D|$. Suppose $\dim |D|=3$ so that the associated map $i$ maps $S$ into $\mathbb{P}^3$. Further suppose that this $i$ is an embedding so that $i(S)$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Then is there a way to compute the degree of $i(S)$? By definition $\deg i(S)$ is the intersection number of $i(S)\cdot \mathbb{P}^1$ where $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a generic line in $\mathbb{P}^3$. I'm wondering is there a way to relate this intersection number with the divisor $D$.

The degree is equal to $D^2$.
